# Session Lifetime in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, session

Currently i'm trying to set session lifetime in springboot project.

**web.xml**

```
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
        </session-config>
```

But session will remain active and reset every time there is activity (e.g. refresh page).

Question: setting session-timeout in web.xml should be reset when activity? or maintain session from the first create even theres activity?

In case i want to set session lifetime to 20 minutes either theres activity or not and clear the session. What should i do to make the session experience like that?

Comment: Session Timeout is for inactivity not session lifetime.

Comment: Is there any way to set session lifetime in spring boot ? @M.Deinum

Comment: No there isn't.